# Compare output of file with string / list or whatever in ansible when statement

Tags: python, ansible

Let's say that content of file "/etc/my_file.txt" is like this:

```
a b CC d
a c BB d
a d DD e
```

I am checking it and writing output to variable:

```
- name: Check 3rd column of file
  shell: cat /etc/my_file.txt | awk '{print $3}'
  register: test
```

**Is there a way to check if the 3rd column of that file has values EXACTLY the same as given in debug section bellow ?**

I've tried to converting it into a list:

```
- set_fact:
   std_out: "{{ test.stdout.split()|list   }}"
```

... and then comparing it with particular list items:

```
- name: Test if it worked
  debug:
     msg: Values are differrent
  when: std_out[0] == "CC" and std_out[1] == "BB" and std_out[2] == "DD"
```

but got errors like this:

```
The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected char u'"'
```

Tried couple more things but still got some issues and feeling like banging my head against the wall :-) Any help would be apprieciated.

My setup is:

```
ansible 2.9.14
python version = 2.7.5
```

Comment: You are missing a closing double quote in your set fact task => `std_out: "{{ test.stdout.split()|list   }}"`, and your `when` clause is also missing a double quote =>  `when: std_out[0] == "CC" and std_out[1] == "BB" and std_out[2] == "DD"`

Comment: Note: I am absolutely not sure this will actually solve your logic problem...

Comment: Well spoted, but of course it was not the real case. I was simply re-writing code and made that silly mistakes. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the registered value, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Check 3rd column of file
      shell: cat my_file.txt | awk '{print $3}'
      register: test
```

gives

```yaml
  test.stdout_lines:
  - CC
  - BB
  - DD
```

You can compare the lists, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Values are differrent
      when: test.stdout_lines != ['CC', 'BB', 'DD']
    - debug:
        msg: Values are not differrent
      when: test.stdout_lines == ['CC', 'BB', 'DD']
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Values are not different
```